# Footer Formatting issue, probably a CSS issue?

Tags: html, css, formatting, format, footer

the URL is http://thebusslab.com/teaching.html

If you look at the footer you can clearly see the formatting issue. Check any other page on the site to see how the footer should appear. I can't figure out if this is an HTML or a CSS issue. If I remove the entire body section of the page the error corrects itself? Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the relevant code (HTML and CSS) here, rather than adding a link to another website (you can click on the 'edit' link to add it to your post). See [how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: btw, on a usability front, the size and colour of the text make it hard to read the links in the footer--there is not enough contrast to make them legible.

Comment: Your site has errors, you can look in the code and see unclosed divs. Main is not started but closed on the page you are referring to. Validate the pages, clean up the code.

Answer (score 2):

it looks like in html of footer you have different nesting compare to other pages, your footer in teaching.html is enclosed under  `<b>` tag and because of that it is picking up different css styles from styles.css but in other pages it is directly under 
 `<div class="container">`

see the difference here is your teaching.html dom
[image]

here is your other pages dom
[image]

Comment: The `<b>` tag is a deprecated tag that makes text bold. All the other items in the footer are links, which have the font weight set to 'normal', but the non-link text is bold, which is making it too wide to fit in the gap it is supposed to go into.

Answer (score 0):

The footer is nested inside two `<b>` tags:

```
<b><b> <!--main-->

    <!-- ================================================== Footer ================================================ -->
    <footer class="lessmarginTopBottom">
```

Remove the `<b>` tags and the text 'Designed by Evan Buss' is no longer bold, so it fits into the space and doesn't get pushed down to the next line.

I'm sure that it was added accidentally, but note that the `<b>` tag is deprecated and should not be used for making text bold; font weight and text decoration should be specified in the stylesheets.